# What is the pressure inside a regular plastic bottle of water?

Tags: pressure, temperature

How do I find out how much pressure there is inside a regular bottle of water made of plastic that we drink? I want to calculate using the *Ideal Gas Law* to find moles for my water bottle.

$PV = nRt$

I already know the temperature. When I leave the bottle outside at room temperature, it should be around $32$ Celcius. The volume is indicated on the bottle, which is around $330$ millimeters. However, I do not know how to find the $P$ or pressure in this equation. $R$ is a constant. So if my understanding is correct, the missing $P$ will give me the number of moles $(n)$?

Comment: Water is not an ideal gas. Also not a gas.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I want to calculate to find the no. of moles of the water inside the bottle, what equation should I use?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of a bottle of soda. If you shake it, the bottle gets more rigid because the pressure inside goes up. That is because shaking makes gas come out of the soda in into the space above the soda. More gas in the same space causes an increase in gas pressure. The gas presses on the soda, which causes the same pressure in the soda.

Comment: @mmesser314 actually no. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-Fc08X56R0  additionally, https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2343556

Comment: You need to specify the conditions you have in mind. As is now, people are trying to guess what the question is. So, is there water in the bottle or just air? Is the cap on or is the bottle open?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know the pressure of the gas that is in the volume above the water. You need to know the composition of that gas. If it is pure H2O vapor, and if you use the volume of the gas, you will get the pressure of the gas.  But in fact it will likely be much more complicated than that.  Water from a tap has a lot of air dissolved in it, so you would need to account  for the amount of dissolved air.  You would also need to account for any ambient air remaining in the.bottle.